# Callbacks from nested functions

Tags: javascript

I have a function such as this:

```
//parent function
function myFirstFunction(param1, callback) {
      //outside inside
      mySecondFunction(param1,function(error,result){
              if(error){ //should return 'error in mySecondFunction' to whoever called this  }
              else{
                   myThirdFunction(error2,result2){
                        if(error2){ //should return 'error in myThirdFunction' to whoever called this }
                        else{ //should return 'Success in myThirdFunction' to whoever called this }
                   });
              }
      });

});
```

I then call this function such as this:

```
myFirstfunction(p1, function(e,r){
      if(e){ console.log('The error returned is : ' + e) };
      else{console.log('Success! The message returned should be Success in myThirdFunction. Is it?  ' + r );}
});
```

I am confused where to put the callbacks inside of nested functions. For instance if I didn't have any nested functions I would simply return callback(null, 'Success in first function') in the body. How can I return these messages back to whatever called them so they know if there were any errors or if it made it all the way to the 3rd function successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything right! You can just call the callback as you passed it in myFirstFunction with each error i.e.

```
  function myFirstFunction(param1, callback) {
  //outside inside
      mySecondFunction(param1,function(error,result){
          if(error){
             callback("error in mySecondFunction");
          }
          else{
               myThirdFunction(error2,result2){
                    if(error2){ 
                      callback("error in myThirdFunction");
                   }
                    else{ 

                      callback(null,result2);//I'm not sure what data you want here
                   }
               });
          }
  });

});
```